# ajax post return the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax function (refer below)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "processor.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: { 'id' : "itemid, 'itemname' : itemname, 'itemdesc' : itemdesc" } ,
    success:function(e){
        if(($.trim(e) == "success")){
            alert("success");
        }else{
            alert(e);
        }  
    },error:function(){
        alert("critical error");
    }
});
```

assume that I already have the linked script of jquery and the content of those variables that has been declared on the data argument inside ajax function. Now I have a processor.php (refer below)

```
//this is the processor php
echo "success";
```

so base from above references, the ajax function submit a post request to processor.php and then the processor.php will respond "success" string as declared with the "echo success" but what happen is it doesn't get the success response instead the whole html tags on the current page is pop up (alert), why?? any ideas, clues, recommendation, suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

PS: i know the response is not success but why it popup (alert) the whole html tags in the current page?

Comment: I suppose there is some redirection happening. What happens if you visit `processor.php` in your browser directly?

Comment: it echoed "success" successfully.

Comment: your php echo out a formated html? send an ajax with „success” as attribute, and parse the json(you won't need trim anymore)

Comment: inside the processor.php is "<?php echo "success"; ?> and I use trim just to make I get the exact response (success) without any whitespaces.

Comment: @cox: I even remove the trim and leave just only "alert(e);" but sadly,  It gives me same popup (all html in an alert thing)

Comment: What all html is on alert? Also, use ===, „==” will check object, not content of a string

Comment: You may use dataType:"json" in ajax and echo json_encode(an php_array["success"]="success")

Comment: Let me know if this works - [http://jsfiddle.net/na9p05f0/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/na9p05f0/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been experienced that before, check your folder and file structure and if you're running server side script (such as php) or communicating with database, check your virtual host configuration.

Comment: thank you! its a virtual host configuration issue thats why my ajax function is missed up.

Answer (score 0):

there is syntax error in posted data and you probably have a redirect to new page instead of processor.php.

EDIT

Also make sure that processor.php returns only the word "success" and there is no more html tags in the source of page.

wrong syntax:

```
data: { 'id' : "itemid, 'itemname' : itemname, 'itemdesc' : itemdesc" }
```

suggested change:

```
data: { id : itemid, itemname : itemname, itemdesc : itemdesc }
```

Comment: still having the same issue, i even tried to change the post type to GET and change the entire script to $(document).ready(function(){ alert("asdsad"); }); just to make sure my jquery is working.

Comment: Please check added paragraph to my answer. What HTML content do you receive? are those tags in the source of processor.php or unknown tags or content of current page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think your are passing parameter is wrong way.i just create an example change this code as per your requirement.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "script.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: { id : itemid, itemname : itemname, itemdesc : itemdesc },
    success: function(data, status, settings)  
        {  
           alert(The request URL and DATA);
        }  
        ,
        error: function(ajaxrequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError)  
        {  
             alert("error");
        }  
});
```